# IntelliJ - 1 Project - support 2 versions of an imported library?

Tags: import, intellij-idea

I'm using a 3rd party addon for my Android Application.  I need to quickly create builds with different versions of the library.

Both versions of the library have the same classes.

Thanks,
stringa

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a quick way to switch libraries within one project. A better solution would be 2 different projects set up on the same code base, one project for each library version.

Answer (score 0):

Well. It isn't pretty, but you can add your libraries to 2 different SDK's that you set up.

Then you just change the SDK to build one vs the other.